# Screen flicker effect in jQuery/CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, effects

Does anyone know a way to create a flickering effect? like in Japanese horror movies, when the screen goes *bzzz bzzz* and it flickers.

I didn't find anything on the web. A link, tutorial - anything would be useful.

Comment: Do you have an example of the effect you're trying to recreate? Your description could fit a range of possible effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a fiddle for you, not sure why people are downvoting the question.  This is just one solution, adding and removing a CSS class with display:hidden;.  Click the picture to begin flashing, you can adjust the flashing speed by adjusting the 300 in the math.random variable, lower is faster.

http://jsfiddle.net/seano666/tDWme/1/

```
function flash(){
    var del = Math.floor((Math.random()*300)+50);
    $('#kitten').toggleClass("display").delay(del);
    $('#kitten').promise().done(function(){
        flash();
    });
}
```

EDIT: Added some sound effects to the fiddle, good fun!

Comment: Not to be a party popper, but I'm viewing the fiddle now and…nothing's happening.

Comment: @017Bluefield You have to click on the image to trigger the effect.